# Adding Reply-To header using Postfix if it does not exist in the mail headers

Tags: postfix, redhat

I would like to add a Postfix re-write rule to insert a `Reply-To:` header if there is not one already defined.

This server is a web server with PHP and Perl scripts, we do not want the mail sent from this server to reply back to this server. Some of the scripts specify `Reply-To:` headers, others do not. I want set `Reply-To: webmaster@domain.tld` if the script has not already set one.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better (and easier) to simply rewrite the sender's address; this will have the same effect, as well as doing some hiding of the internal topology (e.g. the sender won't anymore be something like `apache@webserver6.example.com`).

You can easily rewrite the sender of all outgoing mail with [`smtp_generic_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps). For instance, to change the sender of all outgoing mail to `webmaster@example.com`:

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

In `/etc/postfix/generic`:

```
*                       webmaster@example.com
```

Then run `postmap /etc/postfix/generic` and `service postfix reload`.

See [generic(5)](http://www.postfix.org/generic.5.html) for more options on rewriting sender addresses and the [ADDRESS REWRITING README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) for everything you ever wanted to know about address transformations.

Comment: Yep, that will work for changing ALL outgoing mail. Is there a conditional I can use to check if sender=apache then change sender to webmaster@example.com? Some of the scripts set the sender and reply-to so come thing like sales@example.com and accounting@example.com. I do not want to over write those.

Comment: Just use `apache@whatever` instead of the wildcard. But you did say you wanted to rewrite _all_ outgoing mail...